# Jekyll - Yaml Front matter access variable

Tags: ruby, jekyll

Trying to access showFaces in the following yaml

```
facebook   :
    likeButton :
        showFaces : false
```

I get

```
Liquid Exception: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass in post
```

With the code

```
@array = context['page']['facebook']['likeButton']
```

With

```
@array = context['page']['facebook']
```

I get

```
[{"likeButton"=>{"showFaces"=>false}}]
```

So pretty close

I am new to Ruby so any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
facebook :
    - plugin    : likebutton
      showfaces : true
    - plugin    : comments
      showfaces : true
```

solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem might have to do with Identation within the YAML file. You can find several examples here: http://www.yaml.org/start.html, In your example both facebook and likeButton are at the same level.